# How long before a question is closed

Tags: discussion

When a question is flagged should be closed for whatever reason, how long does the author have to either change the question, update it or remove it before it is closed by the community?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no time limit of any sort, there's simply the time until enough community members agree to reach 5 close votes, or someone with moderator/instant close abilities does so.

Comment: Not quite so. [They do age away](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136989/how-do-close-votes-age-away).

Comment: While that wouldn't automatically close questions (which I think OP was informing about), that mechanism is interesting! (and I did not know about it :$)